# Chaining Asynchronous Function Calls with Stripe and Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, axios

So I try to submit an order for which the user entered his/her credit card.

To do so, I call the `order` method that make an API call to Stripe (`createSource`) to create a payment source. Then I post the order parameters to my Rails backend using axios, in which I send the id of the source that was just created (`source.id`).

```
async order() {
      let {source} = await this.props.stripe.createSource({type: 'card', currency: 'eur', owner: {email: this.props.currentUserEmail}});
      axios.post("/orders", {sourceId: source.id,
                              mealId: this.props.mealId,
                              price: this.state.mealPrice,

                              selectedPickupTime: this.state.selectedPickupTime
                            })
}
```

The problem is, I think the source isn't yet created when axios send the post request to the backend, as I get the following error:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` for source.id

How can I change that and wait for source to be created before axios sends the post request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be an error when creating a source. According to stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source-raw) you need to check if the request were successful this way.

```
async order() {
      // Either Source or Error
      let {source, error} = await this.props.stripe.createSource({type: 'card', currency: 'eur', owner: {email: this.props.currentUserEmail}});

      if (error) { // there was an error
        console.error('Unable to create a source due to', error) 
      } else {
        axios.post("/orders", {sourceId: source.id,
                              mealId: this.props.mealId,
                              price: this.state.mealPrice,

                              selectedPickupTime: this.state.selectedPickupTime
                            })
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ! ok, so it is a error handling issue rather than an asynchronous issue ?

Comment: @JulesCorb Right. According to docs the method returns a promise that is always got resolved. So the error is encoded into return value that is either a success (source) or an error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements), it looks like the correct way to do this is:

```
class CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here, which would refresh the page.
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.props.stripe.createSource({type: 'card', currency: 'eur', owner: {email: this.props.currentUserEmail}})
      .then(source => axios.post("/orders", {sourceId: source.id, mealId: this.props.mealId, price: this.state.mealPrice, selectedPickupTime: this.state.selectedPickupTime }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }
};
```

Comment: this seems logic but will `source.id` be defined ? as I do not define createSource as a `const {source}`

Comment: If the promise has resolved with the source, then the source is made available by passing source to the following promise in the chain, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there's an error from the async function. Use try-catch for your implementation in order to handle promise rejection.

```
async order() {
  try {
    let source = await this.props.stripe.createSource({ type: 'card', currency: 'eur', owner: { email: this.props.currentUserEmail }});
    axios.post("/orders", {
      sourceId: source.id,
      mealId: this.props.mealId,
      price: this.state.mealPrice,
      selectedPickupTime: this.state.selectedPickupTime
    });
  }
  catch (err) { // there was an error
    console.error('Unable to create a source due to', error)
  }
}
```